# iPhone X won't turn wifi on (iOS 13.7)

Tags: iphone, ios

A strange thing started happening on my iPhone X (iOS 13.7). The Wifi knob in the settings is set to disabled but no matter how many times I tap on it doesn't turn the wifi on.

I tried resetting network settings in case it got fixed but still no luck.

The funny thing is that if I leave the device for about 2 hours and come back, the wifi is working perfectly until I switch the device off again. So perhaps this eliminates it being a hardware issue..

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: is there a way for my question to be migrated there?

Comment: Other than deleting it here and asking there - through a mod only I believe.

Comment: A disabled button is usually a sign that it can no longer “see” the hardware.  Your WiFi probably died.

Comment: @Allan the strange thing is that if I leave the phone for at least 2 hours and come back, the wifi is turned on and works perfectly until I switch the phone off..( Updating the question to include that information)

Answer (score 1):

Things to try

1. Reboot the phone
2. Settings > General > VPN & Device Management and remove any Profiles, or Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings
   Reset Network should also remove any previous VPN setup, unless managed by MDM.
3. Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings.
   This does not delete personal files/data, but will reset Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Do No Disturb, Notifications, General, Sounds, Brightness & Wallpaper and Privacy.
4. Restore the phone.
5. Take it to Apple.

Note: 4 & 5 will automatically update to iOS 16.5

Comment: I have tried rebooting the phone but I would like to avoid 2 and 3 because I want to stay on iOS 13

Comment: Is it a managed device? Check Settings  > General > VPN & Device Management for any Profiles.

Comment: I have added GlobalProtect app for me to have VPN so there is a configuration for this there. But it was working perfectly until now.

Comment: Then you're down to removing that, then another network reset. If still no joy, then Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Did all that but unfortunately no luck. It was worth trying though...thanks for your answer!